# Include "distance_of_time_in_words" value in JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an index action in my controller that I use to render all posts as JSON:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @posts = Post.all
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { 
      render json: @posts.to_json(:include => { 
        :user => { :only => [:first_name, :last_name]}, 
        :category => { :only => [:name, :id]}
      }), 
      :callback => params[:callback]  
    }
  end
end
```

What I'd like to do, is add an additional attribute to each post's JSON output called `posted_on`, that has a value of: `distance_of_time_in_words(post.created_at, Time.now)}`

I can't seem to be able to figure out how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the method `posted_on` to `Post` model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  def posted_on
    distance_of_time_in_words(created_at, Time.now)
  end
end
```

In your controller, pass the methods option to to_json

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @posts = Post.all
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { 
      render json: @posts.to_json(:include => { 
        :user => { :only => [:first_name, :last_name]}, 
        :category => { :only => [:name, :id]}
      }, :methods => :posted_on), 
      :callback => params[:callback]  
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to output the value of `posted_on` in the JSON. It doesn't throw an exception – but, adding the code above has not impacted the rendered JSON at all. Not sure what's up.

Comment: Did you add the method `posted_on` to your `Post` model?